# React Navigation tabBarOnPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to add event on navigation and navigate to the screen, I have this code but I don't know what's wrong.

When I set `tabBarOnPress` it wouldn't navigate but do the event and if I do not set it I don't know how to trigger the event.

```
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react- 
navigation';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import {
  AdMobInterstitial,
} from 'react-native-admob';

AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-2821491096541440/1777616101');

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Apps recomendadas',
  tabBarOnPress: () => {
   this.somevent();
  },
};

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator({
  Links: LinksScreen,
});

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'FAQ',
  tabBarOnPress: () => {
     this.somevent();
  },
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LinksStack
},);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, but this code worked for me

```
tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
        console.log('onPress:', navigation.state.routeName);
        defaultHandler()
      },
```

If I fail to include `defaultHandler()` the screen does not navigate to display the chosen route and just executes the `console.log` statement only

Comment: I followed this approach but nothing seems to print over the console.